# What's the proper term for 'zzz'

Tags: loops, user-input

When you stop a loop using user input like 'zzz' or '99999', what's that called? I remember learning it a while ago but can't put a name to it.

Comment: Are you looking for [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.